# Ruby Sprockets v4.0 upgrade FileNotFound (assets extension mismatch .coffee, .scss - mime types?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets, rails-sprockets

I recently updated my app to use Sprockets 4.0: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sprockets/4.0.0
I introduced the manifest.js file as described here: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md

My current assets are described in: application.coffee, application.light.coffee, application.scss, application.light.scss files.
On starting the server I get errors of type:

- `couldn't find file 'jquery' with type 'text/coffeescript'`

  - Asset is available with .js extension.
- `couldn't find file 'select2' with type 'text/scss'`

  - Asset is available with .css extention.

I was previously using sprockets v3.7; the gemfiles have correctly been added.
I have tried clearing the tmp/cache after upgrading.

Can someone recommend the path forward here. I have cross-checked all threads for this question.
So far I am resorting to renaming application.coffee -> application.js, application.cscc -> application.css but it doesn't look like the ideal solution.

manifest.js

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

Comment: Maybe you can paste your manifect.js, too?

Comment: @kevinluo201 Done! - I used the standard manifest.js - as per documentation application.coffee and application.scss should also be covered.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was arising because we were precompiling few assets using Rails.application.config.assets.precompile - application.light.coffee, application.light.scss

Once I removed this the issue with extension stopped surfacing.
If anyone has context to why the above errors were thrown will help to clarify the answer.